# C++ Backend Infrastructure

Tags: c++, qt, backend

We have very complex C++ image processing engine, using Intel Compiler, OpenCV, etc.
Currently it is being integrated in our production via C# interop layer, which is so thin, it almost doesn't affect speed performance (and we are talking about few milliseconds per request). Now we are planning to migrate our systems to CentOS (and still support Windows platforms). Historically I don't have much trust in Mono, JNI also has its issues so most logical solution is to move towards pure C++ implementation.

Is it good idea in your opinion, considering we need to port following functionality:

1) Filesystem
2) JSON
3) Threads
4) Storm / Kafka / RabbitMq
5) XML
6) Log2Cxx

By the way I thought maybe about Qt, we don't need UI, but it will cover for us Filesystem, Threads, XML and maybe even JSON.

Many thanks, 
  Pavel

Comment: boost appears to have nearly everything you need

Comment: Mooing Duck, you mean filesystem, threads and what else?

Comment: `boost::property_tree::read_json` and `boost::property_tree::read_xml` come to mind.  I know it has `boost::log` as well.  I'd have to look up what storm at kafka and RabbitMq are, but of the 5 I know, boost has 100%, so that's looking good so far.

Comment: When I do a google search for "Log2Cxx", the only non-code hit that actually contains that text is this question.  I also can't find anything at all about "Storm".

Comment: Since "Kafka" seems to be a message passing system, and "RabbitMq" seems to also be "messaging", there's `boost::asio`, `boost::mpi`, `boost::ipc`, and `boost::signals`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very high chance that your credit card payment was processed at by a system that runs Qt core, so you're on the right track.

Qt is modular. You need a couple of modules that exclude the GUI stuff, although even GUI is usable in a server. It's pretty damn easy to paint some images to send back to the client, for example. I would recommend to use Qt whenever possible and only fall back on Boost if Qt doesn't provide what you need and it can't be implemented in a simple fashion. If you'll be undecided between Qt and boost, you'll end up with a *lot* of glue code that will make the whole thing much more work than necessary.

Qt doesn't have a logging mechanism per se, it has some facilities for debug output, but it needs more if you want real logging. It does cover the file system, json, threading, networking, communication between objects using event queues and/or signal-slot connections. It also has streaming XML parsers. You can integrate your project with log2xx. The durable messaging infrastructure will also need to be integrated since Qt doesn't provide that. You may find out that it's easier to implement just what you need, as far as messaging is concerned.

Asking about speed overhead of threading is a bit pointless, since in almost any framework out there, a thread controller is just a means of starting user code in a thread. It no runtime overhead once a thread is created. Everything depends on what code you run in the thread.

What you want to ask about, thus, is what code would you normally "run" in a thread? Ideally, you want only to run the event loop provided in the default implementation of `QThread`. The event loop synchronizes with other threads only when you're posting messages to it from other threads. That's what any other implementation of inter-thread communications would do anyway, so there's no extra Qt-specific overhead. You then move QObjects into the thread that is to run them (or simply create in code that runs in that thread already).

When you have to encapsulate blocking third-party code, like the notorious blocking database interfaces, then you'll be forced to put every database connection in its own thread. This would be the case whether you use Qt or not, so nothing special there.

Qt's XML and json implementations are reasonable, I don't see why they'd be much worse than anything else out there.

If you're serious about your project, you'll become a customer of Digia. I'm sure they'll answer your questions about what level of support is provided, about the stability, etc.

One benefit of using Qt for your project is that it's cross platform: you can run it on Linux or Windows servers. If it's a system for installation by third parties, this may be an important consideration.

Comment: Does Qt add some speed overhead when talking about XML/Json parsing and threading? Is it stable enough for server side applications? I didn't use Qt for a last 4 years, what are its perspectives? It is not so widely used, wouldn't I risk our project by making it strong dependent on Qt platform? How good its support nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

Qt might also cover Log2Cxx since it has a logging mechanism. You can certainly parse JSON as far as I know on Qt 5.0. QJson is another alternative, you can check out:

http://qjson.sourceforge.net/usage/

Beside Qt, I would recommend Boost library for it is the first library that I would use in C++ when necessary.